# add two data frames together with unequal size

Tags: r, dataframe

I want add data frame A and B together to make data frame C. If a `ID` and `colname` is common between A and B, then I want to just add the two values together. If a `ID` and `colname` is not found in one of the data frames, then just add that to the final data frame C.

I tried `join(B,A,type="left")`, but it is not what I am after.

```
 > A
     ID Pat1 Pat2 Pat3
1 Gene1    1    4    1
2 Gene2    2    0    9
3 Gene3    5    5    5
> B
     ID Pat1 Pat2 Pat3 Pat4
1 Gene1    3    9    1    1
2 Gene2    3    0    0    9
3 Gene3    5    5    5    5
4 Gene4    3    1    3    0
> C
     ID Pat1 Pat2 Pat3 Pat4
1 Gene1    4   13    2    1
2 Gene2    5    0    9    9
3 Gene3   10   10   10    5
4 Gene4    3    1    3    0
```

Dput:

```
> dput(A)
structure(list(ID = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3"), Pat1 = c(1, 
2, 5), Pat2 = c(4, 0, 5), Pat3 = c(1, 9, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
> dput(B)
structure(list(ID = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"), Pat1 = c(3, 
3, 5, 3), Pat2 = c(9, 0, 5, 1), Pat3 = c(1, 0, 5, 3), Pat4 = c(1, 
9, 5, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
> dput(C)
structure(list(ID = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"), Pat1 = c(4, 
5, 10, 3), Pat2 = c(13, 0, 10, 1), Pat3 = c(2, 9, 10, 3), Pat4 = c(1, 
9, 5, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Found out that cast works:   mydf <- dcast(melt(mget(ls(pattern = "....")), id.vars = "ID"), 
             ID ~ variable, value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = sum)

Answer (score 1):

I'll first find out which column is missing between `A` and `B`, then fill the missing column with `NA`. Then `full_join` the two dataframes, `group_by` their `ID`, and `sum` all rows in the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

missing_cols <- setdiff(names(dfB), names(dfA))
  
dfA[missing_cols] <- NA
  
full_join(dfA, dfB) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = T)), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  ID     Pat1  Pat2  Pat3  Pat4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Gene1     4    13     2     1
2 Gene2     5     0     9     9
3 Gene3    10    10    10     5
4 Gene4     3     1     3     0
```

Comment: This works as long as there are no identical rows between the two data frames? If that happened you'd lose one of the dups.

Comment: Not really, because the two dataframe would have different number of columns, and I've set the content of the missing column to `NA`, there would never be identical rows (as long as the number of column differs in the two data frames). For example, "Gene3" from `dfA` and `dfB` in `Pat1`:`Pat3` are identical, but `dfA` don't have `Pat4`. Therefore, the overall pattern for "Gene3" would be `5 5 5 NA` in `dfA` but `5 5 5 5` in `dfB`. They are never identical.

Comment: Oh good point - I forgot about the `NA` column. Great answer!